# Deleting record from sqlite database using Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I can't seem to figure out how to delete a record from a sqlite database created via java.  I was trying to identify the record with the primary id but I just keep getting a null pointer exception. Heres my code:

```
  package userinterface;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    import java.awt.FlowLayout;

    import javax.swing.JButton;

    import javax.swing.JDialog;

    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    import backend.SQLiteDb;

    import business.Person;

    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    public class GUI {

        static SQLiteDb db;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            final JFrame jframe = new JFrame();

            JButton btnEnterInfo = new JButton("Enter Info");

            jframe.getContentPane().add(btnEnterInfo, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            jframe.setVisible(true);

            jframe.setSize(300, 300);

            btnEnterInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    JLabel fullName = new JLabel("Full Name: ");

                    JTextField nameField = new JTextField();

                    JLabel age = new JLabel("Age: ");

                    JTextField ageField = new JTextField();

                    JLabel address = new JLabel("Address: ");

                    JTextField addressField = new JTextField();

                    JLabel salary = new JLabel("Salary: ");

                    JTextField salaryField = new JTextField();

                    Object[] ob = { fullName, nameField, age, ageField, address,
                            addressField,

                            salary, salaryField };

                    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, "Part 5",

                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

                    jframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

                        db = new SQLiteDb();

                        db.createPersonnelTable();
                        String fullName1 = nameField.getText();
                        String userAge = ageField.getText();
                        String userAddress = addressField.getText();
                        String userSalary = salaryField.getText();
                        Person person = new Person(fullName1, Integer
                                .parseInt(userAge), userAddress,

                        Double.parseDouble(salaryField.getText()));

                        db.addPerson(person);

                        String sql = "SELECT * FROM COMPANY";

                        Statement stmt = null;

                        try {
                            java.sql.Statement s;

                            Connection connection = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("JDBC:sqlite:Andy.db");
                            stmt = connection.createStatement();
                            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                            while (rs.next()) {
                                int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
                                String name = rs.getString("name");
                                int age1 = rs.getInt("Age");
                                String address1 = rs.getString("Address");
                                double salary1 = rs.getInt("Salary");

                                String output = id_col + " " + name + " " + age1
                                        + " " + address1 + " " + salary1;
                                System.out.println(output);

                            }
                            delete(3);
                            rs.close();
                        } catch (SQLException ee) {
                            System.out.println("ee error");
                            ee.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {
                            if (stmt != null) {
                                try {
                                    stmt.close();

                                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    System.out.println("e1 error");
                                    e1.printStackTrace();

                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
            });

        }

        public static void viewTable(Connection con, String dbName)
                throws SQLException {

        }

        public static void delete(int id) {
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
            try {
                // connection = DriverManager.getConnection();
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person WHERE id = ?");
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("DELETE FROM person WHERE id = ?");
            } catch (Exception eeee) {
                eeee.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                if (preparedStatement != null) {
                    try {
                        preparedStatement.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    try {
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }
            }}}
```

Comment: Jason my friend please add stackstrace and point us to that line and why this `// connection = DriverManager.getConnection();` line commented?

Comment: Do you have a debugger handy?

Comment: Please remove the double-spacing so that I don't have to scroll so much to read your code. White space should be used to make reading code easier for other people.

Answer (score 1):

`connection` is null in your delete method, why wouldn't you get NullPointerException?

```
 Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        // connection = DriverManager.getConnection(); <--- !!!! This line is commented for some reason, so it is not executed!
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person WHERE id = ?");
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

The rest of your code in your delete method looks ok, you just need to initialize your connection variable to something.

A possible solution is to store this variable in a method field instead of a local variable when you are initializing it in your `actionPerformed` method:

```
this.connection = DriverManager
                            .getConnection("JDBC:sqlite:Andy.db");
```

Then you could use:

```
preparedStatement = this.connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person WHERE id = ?");
```

which would re-use the previously initialized connection. (Re-using connection object is a good idea)

Comment: Oh ok. I think I fixed it now. I no longer get null pointer exception but my entry with the primary id of 3 is still there. delete(3); isnt working. I still see the entry in the database I re-updated the code I originally posted above